# System.Web.Helpers Namespace not working in WebMatrix

Tags: c#, razor, namespaces, webmatrix, webimage

Im trying to use the `WebImage` object type in `WebMatrix 3`.
It works fine in the `.cshtml` file, but when doing the same thing in a `.cs` file it can't find the type.
I've tried adding the `Using System.Web.Helpers` but nothing happens.

Any suggestions on how to fix it or whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occours sometimes in `WebMatrix 3`. After restarting my pc it all worked again.